# Java Class: How would I make a class that returns a string parameter but can also be used as an entry point for an application?

Tags: java, ipc

Following the "PIPE WITH STRINGS" section of this tutorial: http://www.jonathanbeard.io/tutorials/CtoJava

I want to modify the StreamTest code so that I can save the data to a variable and pass it to another class.

I tried doing that (See Below) but when I run **java -cp . StreamTest**
from the tutorial I get this:

*Main method not found in class StreamTest, please define the main method 
as: public static void main(String[] args)*

Which makes sense I guess, but I am kind of stuck on how to approach this now.

**The main idea is that I want to be able to get the data from the c code, put it in the variable pass (I guess through the StreamTest code), and then pass that variable to my mainLaptop class**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class StreamTest
{
private static final int buffer = 4096;
public static String main(String [] args, String pass)
{

    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    try
    {
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(System.in,buffer);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append((char)bis.read());
        while(bis.available() > 0)
        {
            sb.append((char)bis.read());
        }

        System.out.println("JAVA SIDE: "+sb.toString());
        pass=sb.toString();
        bis.close();

    }
    catch(IOException ex){}
    finally{}
    //return pass;
    return pass;

}
}
```

Here is the main class I want to pass the data into

```
public class mainLaptop 
{

public static void main(String arg) throws Exception 
{   
    //Timing out? change the IP!
    String ip="192.168.137.127";
    String Pi1Q1="Leonardo";
    String Pi1Q2="Raphael";
    String Pi2Q3="Donatello";
    String Pi2Q4="Michelangelo";
    String pass=arg;
    //pass= StreamTest.main(pass);

    Send.send(ip, Pi1Q1, pass);
    Send.send(ip, Pi1Q2, pass);
    Send.send(ip, Pi2Q3, pass);
    Send.send(ip, Pi2Q4, pass);

/*  Recv.recv(ip, Pi1Q1);
    Recv.recv(ip, Pi1Q2);
    Recv.recv(ip, Pi2Q3);
    Recv.recv(ip, Pi2Q4);*/
}
}
```

Here is the unmodified StreamTest that works

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class StreamTest
   {
    private static final int buffer = 4096;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
  {   
    String pass=null;
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    try
    {
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(System.in,buffer);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //sb.append((char)bis.read());
        while(bis.available() > 0){
            sb.append((char)bis.read());
        }
        pass = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("JAVA SIDE: "+sb.toString());
        bis.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {

    }

    finally
    {


    }

  //  mainLaptop.main(pass);

}
```

Here is the c code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define DEBUG 0
#define BUFFER 4096

//open ap.txt for text input
static const char* exFile = "ap.txt";
static char inputBuffer[BUFFER];

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
   FILE *fp = fopen(exFile,"r");
   /*check and see if the pointer is null in otherwords see if the memory 
   location refered to by fp is set...no memory location should be zero 
   if you want to reference it   
   Here are some good ways to do this other than the way I did it below:
   if(!fp) {do error}
   if(fp == NULL) {do error}
   and then there's the way I did it below
   */

   if(fp == 0){
      fprintf(stderr,"Null pointer exception, check file name.\n");
      exit(-1);
   }

   //check and see if an error occured during open
   const int err = ferror(fp);
   if(err != 0){
      /*
     void perror(const char* err)
     returns specific error message to string attached.

     */
  const char* errMessage = strcat("Something bad happened while opening 
  file ",exFile);
  perror(errMessage);
   }
     #if (DEBUG == 1)   
    else
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"Success opening file!!\n");
    }  
    #endif




setbuf(fp,inputBuffer); //set a buffer for input

uint64_t *num = (uint64_t*) malloc(sizeof(uint64_t));
uint64_t total = 0;
uint64_t n = 0;

//test for eof
/*
feof(*fp) - returns a boolean true if at end of file and false otherwise
*/

while(!feof(fp)){
//fscanf returns the number of items it converted using %llu, if it's not 
 equal to 1 we don't want to continue
   if(fscanf(fp,"%"PRIu64"",num)!=1)
  break; //you could do a lot of stuff here as far as error handling but 
basically something bad has happened
   total+= *num; //add to total the value at memory location num
   n++;
    #if (DEBUG == 1)   
    fprintf(stderr,"line number %"PRIu64"\n",n);
    #endif 
    }

    free(num);

const double average = (double) total / (double) n;
//close the inputfile
fclose(fp);

//declare our outputfile, use a pipe in this case to a java process
//we open a java process for this process to pipe to, also it is 
//technically a bi-directional pipe so we can use any of the modifiers
//like r/w/r+/etc
static const char* outFile = "java -cp . StreamTest";

FILE *fp_out = popen(outFile,"w");
//setbuf(fp_out,outputBuffer);

fprintf(fp_out,"Total: %"PRIu64", Integers: %"PRIu64", Average: 
%.4f\n",total,n,average);



/*
int fflush(*fp) pushes any data in the buffer to be written
the return value returns 0 if successful or !=0 if an error 
occurs....remember return values in C often equal exceptions

*/   
   fflush(fp_out);

/*

int 

 */
    fclose(fp_out);

   return 1;
}
```

Here is the make file

```
CC ?=gcc
JCC ?= javac
FLAGS ?= -Wall -O2
JFLAGS ?= -g -verbose

all: c_app StreamTest

c_app: c_app.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o c_app c_app.c

StreamTest: StreamTest.java
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) StreamTest.java $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f c_app StreamTest.class
```

The ap.text file is just a bunch of numbers

I've updated my StreamTest code and run it through eclipse but my output is

```
JAVA SIDE: 
 [x] Sent ''Leonardo
 [x] Sent ''Raphael
 [x] Sent ''Donatello
 [x] Sent ''Michelangelo
```

instead of

```
JAVA SIDE: 
 [x] Sent 'Total: 4953, Integers: 1000, Average: 4.9530'Leonardo
 [x] Sent 'Total: 4953, Integers: 1000, Average: 4.9530'Raphael
 [x] Sent 'Total: 4953, Integers: 1000, Average: 4.9530'Donatello
 [x] Sent 'Total: 4953, Integers: 1000, Average: 4.9530'Michelangelo
```

Updated StreamTest

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class StreamTest
{
private static final int buffer = 4096;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    String pass=null;
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    try
    {
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(System.in,buffer);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //sb.append((char)bis.read());
        while(bis.available() > 0){
            sb.append((char)bis.read());
        }
        pass = sb.toString();
        System.out.println("JAVA SIDE: "+pass);
        bis.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {

    }

    finally
    {


    }
    //pass = "hi";
    mainLaptop.main(pass);

}    
}
```

Comment: `main()` is the entry point - if the other class is part of the same Java application you can invoke its method from main, passing the string you have.

Comment: I am invoking the StreamTest class to my other class like this:      
String pass=null;
pass= StreamTest.main(arg, pass);                                                                   But before I run that class/application I need to run StreamTest from the terminal like so:                                                                            1 make StreamTest
2 make c_app
3 java -cp . StreamTest
4 ./c_app
but again the problem is at Step 3. I get the error above (in my post) because instead of this: public static void main(String[] args)
I have it as public static String

Comment: I think you have a design problem here. Maybe posting your complete requirements would help. As is, this is a XY problem. You're doing something counter-intuitive, but maybe your requirements demand that - we cannot know unless you describe

Comment: I was thinking of running these commands 1 make StreamTest 2 make c_app 3 java -cp . StreamTest 4 ./c_app in the terminal than comiling and running mainLaptop in eclipse but maybe that is not the right way to do it

Comment: But the main idea is that I want to be able to get the data from the c code, put it in the variable pass, and then pass that variable to my mainLaptop class

Comment: Classes don't return methods, and classes aren't entry points. Classes have *methods*, and methods can return strings, or be entry points ('public static void main(String[] args)').

Comment: I've updated my code so that I invoke mainLaptop in StreamTest but I'm not getting the output I want. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it all wrong ... you are running

> java -cp

So this is trying to run your application, hence the error, that it cant find a Main method because Java looks for a Main method when trying to run an application...

If you want to save the data just pass the data into the command like so

> java -cp . class "the string you want"

And then in the main method you have the "String args[]"  read it from that :)

**EDITED**

@Jas Buddy what are you doing ??? how can you have two main Method ....? scrap StreamTest use only mainLaptop ....

```
public class mainLaptop 
{

public static void main(String arg) throws Exception 
{   
    //Timing out? change the IP!
    String ip="192.168.137.127";
    String Pi1Q1="Leonardo";
    String Pi1Q2="Raphael";
    String Pi2Q3="Donatello";
    String Pi2Q4="Michelangelo";
    String pass=arg[0]; // reads the argument you pass from command line or eclipse
    //pass= StreamTest.main(pass);

    Send.send(ip, Pi1Q1, pass);
    Send.send(ip, Pi1Q2, pass);
    Send.send(ip, Pi2Q3, pass);
    Send.send(ip, Pi2Q4, pass);

/*  Recv.recv(ip, Pi1Q1);
    Recv.recv(ip, Pi1Q2);
    Recv.recv(ip, Pi2Q3);
    Recv.recv(ip, Pi2Q4);*/
}
}
```

IF you are running it from eclipse
 Right click run-->Run configuration--> Arguments 
[image]

Output will be  "teenagemutant" because we have taken only args[0], if you want the other values then arg[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPBLj.png),args[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Mq1.png)...

if you want to run it on commandLine then
[image]

Comment: ok so if I want to put the data into my class mainLaptop (I've added it above) all I have to do is java -cp . mainLaptop"pass" ?

Comment: @Jas pretty much yeah... try it without the quotes like "java -cp . mainLaptop pass"  and you should be able to get it like so in your main method  using args[0]

Comment: I get Error: Could not find or load main class mainLaptop
even though I change the c code to have mainLaptop instead of StreamTest

Comment: that's a class path issue are you inside a package ??

Comment: I can send u an export of my project. I have StreamTest, mainLaptop, and Send classes/files all in a src package. I've updated my post with how my StreamTest class looks now, but data isn't being passed to my pass variable when I run StreamTest in eclipse